# Entering .htaccess-protected directory using a form

Tags: .htaccess, forms

A password-protected area of a website I work on has always been entered by linking to the address, which presents the user with a dialog to enter their username and password.

I would like to use a form to enter that information, but I can't work out how it's done and whether it's possible. Help please!

Edit: Does anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP authentication](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) is different from form authentication where the processing script authenticates the client. The form data is send in either the URL (GET) or the HTTP message body (POST). But HTTP authentication requires the data to be send in a specific HTTP header field ([`WWW-Authenticate`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.47)) and there’s no way to get form data into that field for HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489)

I know that's not a solution, but it may prove relevant depending on what recommendations you get here.